# Killing more attractive mates -- intersexual selection strategy?

Tags: natural-selection, sexual-selection

Is this the affinity or core part of intersexual selection (males fighting for access to females)?

If females are bound to flock to objectively more attractive man 'A' in the majority of cases, would killing him put odds in your favor? It's all relative, no? If a guy is better looking than you and you kill him, he's obviously no longer better looking and alive -- so he can't reproduce. If you killed every better looking man than yourself, wouldn't you become the next best looking man? Sounds about right.

But is this not the core reasons for mating? Kill off all the good looking men and then you're hottest.

Since no guy alive can be more attractive than you, you have sex with all of the women. Not crazy.....?

I mean in theory of course..... we know what makes men sexier -- jaws, cheekbones, eye shape, height, size/muscles, symmetry, facial width to height ratio, skin complexion/coloring/etc. So yeah....

Comment: I suspect this question hasn't been downvoted because it suggests murder as a strategy, but because it's not well formulated as a question. What exactly are you asking with "So yeah..."?

Comment: It's not a form of intersexual selection; it's an intrasexual selection strategy.

Comment: This is why there are fights between males for dominance (and having access to females) in many species. Humans have survived all these years through cooperation. So, no, its a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious flaw in this (as applied to humans) is that once the more attractive males discover that you are killing them off, they are likely to gang up and kill you instead.  Futher details likely could be found on the Law site :-)

This would seem to have a serious flaw as a general strategy, too.  Sexual attractiveness would seem to correlate with general fitness, so that if you try to kill that more attractive male (without the sneaky means of killing that technology provides), there is a good chance that he'll wind up killing you instead.

Answer (score 1):

> If a guy is better looking than you and you kill him, he's obviously
>   no longer better looking and alive -- so he can't reproduce.

Animals can't go around shiving each other.  This less attractive bird or whatever probably can't kill a healthy member of its species without a brutal fight.  They might both end up dead.

Have you thought about what happens to the population numbers as the "kill my rivals" gene becomes more common widespread?

Anyway, we already have plenty of species where one male keeps a harem of females.  And yes, they do get attacked by others seeking to take over their mates.